# Line instead of Dot (R) Not so easy

Tags: r, plot

If you could help me it would be great : 
So i'm doing a double curve (SDT) graph, and i have a bit of a problem : here my graph : 
[image: Dot]
[image: type = "l"]

First time I have this problem ... Really have no clue how to solve it, well I just think my data is not ordered but how can I order it easily ?

Here's me code (but really nothing special) :

```
x = TDSindice2$Hit
mean = mean(x)
sd = sd(x)

y = dnorm(x,mean,sd)

plot(x,y, col = "red")


x = TDSindice2$Fa
mean = mean(x)
sd = sd(x)

y = dnorm(x,mean,sd)
par(new=TRUE)

plot(x,y ,type = "l", col ="blue")
```

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Sort your data in increasing order of `x`. And learn about `lines()`! :-)

Comment: I know lines(), i just thought it might have been the problem, and forgot to change that before posting there ... ( it wasn't the problem at stake ^^) 

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: personally, I like the triangles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to order your data in terms of increasing values of `x` *before* plotting. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50)
y <- 1.2 + (1.4 * x) + (-2.5 * x^2)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, y)
```

[image]

The `order()` function can be used to generate an index that when applied to a variable/object places the values of that object in the required order (increasing by default):

```
ord <- order(x)
plot(x[ord], [ord], type = "o")
```

[image]

But you'd be better off have `x` and `y` in the same object, a data frame, and just sort the rows of that:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
ord <- with(dat, order(x))
plot(y ~ x, data = dat[ord, ], type = "o") ## or
## lines(y ~ x, data = dat[ord, ])
```

Note that `order()` is used to index the data hence we don't change the original ordering, we just permute the rows as we supply the object to the `plot()` function.

Comment: or even `plot(y~x, data=plyr::arrange(dat,x), ...)`